# Query Select Row and Column together one statement

Tags: google-sheets, filter, count, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I work on a google sheet, where I should see the number of holidays per day for each team.

The table looks like this:
[table][image: 1]

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Employee Name | Team Name | 01/03/2022 | 02/03/2022 | 03/03/2022 |
| 2 | Employee 1 | Team A | hol | hol | hol |
| 3 | Employee 2 | Team B | early | early | early |
| 4 | Employee 3 | Team A | hol | late | late |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | Team A |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | 01/03/2022 |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | RESULT HERE |  |  |  |  |

I want to have a result that tells me that Team A had on 01/03/2022 2 holidays.

```
=countif(query(A1:E4,"select C where B contains '"&A6&"'" ),"hol")
```

A6 contains the team I am looking for. 
A7 contains the date I am looking for.
A8 should show me the number of hol.

Currently, I have a fixed column to look inside which is "C". I want to replace that with the date from A7 - How do I do that?
I tried to play around with transpose and filter but had success.

Comment: In the preview, the table looks fine, but here it's somehow weird. I made it with a markdown table. I don't know what's wrong with the parser.

Comment: Alex, Don't worry. You did good formatting. Have a upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(FILTER(C2:E4, C1:E1=A7), B2:B4=A6), "hol")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `XMATCH` to get the `Col` number  for `QUERY` and `count` inside query instead of `COUNTIF`:

```js
=QUERY(
  {B1:E4},
  "Select count(Col1) 
    where Col"&XMATCH(A7,B1:E1)&"='hol' 
    and Col1='"&A6&"' 
    label count(Col1) ''",
  1
)
```